# Algorithm to trigger bulk events by schedule

Tags: node.js, redis

I'd like to create a web app that allows users to do email outreach, but I'm having trouble with a good solution.

I'd like each user to be able to send 100 emails per day, which would be configurable during certain times, e.g. 6 am to 10 am. I'm able to determine a delivery schedule per user (based on times that they configure), but b/c users can change their email schedules at any time, I'd have to reconfigure the order of processing.

Is there a queue type in Redis (for instance) that triggers by time?
Or a way to trigger events on a schedule in nodejs that's scalable?

Answer (score 0):

There is a  Redis feature: Keyspace notifications, which allow clients to subscribe to Pub/Sub channels in order to receive redis events( an example event is a"key expiry" event).

Documentation: http://redis.io/topics/notifications

For your use case, you can maybe use the "key expiry" event.

Comment: For answer's with link(s), it is advisable  to highlight the important details or provide a summary regarding what you found in the link you provided. Because time will come that the link will be unavailable/invalid.